# Use URL slug in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I can create without problem a record slug with the title in cakephp 3.x. Now I want to use that field slug on the URL.

How can I do that?

I try with the typical function view changing $id by $slug...

```
 public function view($slug = null)
        {
            $noticia = $this->Noticias->get($slug, [
                'contain' => ['Categorias', 'Usuarios', 'Etiquetas', 'Fotos']
            ]);
            $this->set('noticia', $noticia);
            $this->set('_serialize', ['noticia']);
        }
```

but I have the following error: "Record not found in table "noticias".

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get()` method can only be used to find record by primary key. Instead, you need to use `find()`:

```
$noticia = $this->Noticias
     ->findBySlug($slug)
    ->contain(['Categorias', 'Usuarios', 'Etiquetas', 'Fotos'])
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thank you once more José :-)